# how do I apply a class to the header cell for a column in slickgrid

Tags: css, slickgrid

I have a column in slickgrid where all the cells need to have some padding applied to the right side of the cell. I use the cssClass property when initializing the columns for the grid, but this applies only to the non-header cells of the column. How do I specify a css class to use for the header as well so I can apply the right padding to it as well? Without that padding, the header cell becomes slightly out of line with the rest of the cells below it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If these styles apply to all cells, you can style them using the built-in `.slick-cell` and `.slick-headerrow-column` CSS classes.  One thing to watch out for, however, is that your styles may not override SlickGrid's defaults if they have lower rule specificity.  If that's an issue in your app, either increase specificity of your rules or use `!important` - `.slick-cell { padding-right:10px !important; }`.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to apply it to all cells or all columns - I only want to apply it to one columns header cell. I can set it for all cells in a given column, but not that header cell. I can't find anything short of selecting the nth column in the div.slick-headerrow-column jquery selected list and applying css that way to specify the column header I need. It seems like an overworked approach to styling one single header cell.

Comment: Oh, I see.  In that case, you can specify a CSS class for a column header via the column definition - columnDef.headerCssClass.