# How can i change slickgrid header background color based on a condition?

Tags: css, angular, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

I am using a angular-slickgrid = 2.30.2 ,Angular 10, i am using styles.css where i am loading the slickgrid theme through bootstrap .sass file.
i have created a shared slickgrid component and using it in parent components wherever required.

1. i want to change the slick grid header color based on a condition in my parent component.
   For e.g if my variable value is true then show slickgrid header blue else red, how can i do that?

2. i want to add bottom border for every third row in grid for only one screen/component which is using slick grid, how can I implement that.

i am new to slickgrid , please guide.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I'm the author of Angular-Slickgrid, there are already plenty of SO questions and answers on how to style SlickGrid, take for example these:

- [Setting SlickGrid cell styling based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517733/setting-slickgrid-cell-styling-based-on-cell-value)
- [how do I apply a class to the header cell for a column in slickgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401138/how-do-i-apply-a-class-to-the-header-cell-for-a-column-in-slickgrid)
- [Angular SlickGrid align header text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70275543/angular-slickgrid-align-header-text)
- [How to add a class to a cell in SlickGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742166/how-to-add-a-class-to-a-cell-in-slickgrid/14757131#14757131)

and/or simply use the Column properties `cssClass` or `headerCssClass` from the [Column](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/blob/master/packages/common/src/interfaces/column.interface.ts#L166) interface. I added TypeScript types for everything in latest version which should give you enough indication of what you can try.

Also please remember that Angular-Slickgrid is a wrapper of SlickGrid, searching for SlickGrid will always provide you more result to your question searches

Lastly you're on an older version (2.x) that I no longer support, you should think about migrating eventually to get access to newer features and smaller builds, see [Migration Guide 3.x](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Migration-to-3.x) and [Migration Guide 4.x](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Migration-to-4.x)